# Stolen MacBook Pro - Locating via Serial Number

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, geolocation, serial-number

Someone has broken into my apartment and stolen my MacBook Pro and my roommate's Mac. Neither of the two devices was logged in to iCloud. Is there a way to track my device through its serial number?

Comment: According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204756), Find My Mac is the only Apple service that can help track or locate a lost Mac. If you didn’t set up Find My Mac before your Mac was lost, or you can’t locate it. Your best bet would be to "report your lost or stolen Mac to local law enforcement. They might request the serial number of your computer." - Apple. There are databases for submitting lost device's serial numbers, these alert buyers for example when a device is marked stolen. I'd recommend getting onto this as soon as possible.

Comment: Is there a way to locate my Mac by serial number?

Comment: Same question in question and subsequent comment : answer NO - you did not sign up for the Apple service so you can’t use find my mac. All you can do is report it stolen and give the police the serial number - then make suitable offerings to the computer gods ...

Comment: @ShakibFarah Were you successful in any of my steps listed below? I'd like to follow up with on this.

Comment: If such a service existed, it would be a privacy nightmare. You could track anyone’s MacBook simply by knowing the serial number, since it couldn’t require that you have physical access to the machine to prove it was yours. That’s why it doesn’t exist.

Comment: There's a labor intensive, low probability of success option. If you have backups including system logs, check /var/log/daily.out for the network status report. From there, you can get the MAC ID for the AirPort card. You can then check public WiFi networks for the MAC ID. You might also be able to enlist the aid of whoever runs those public networks to keep an eye out for the MAC ID and report it to the police. Speaking from experience, iCloud is also of limited usefulness when it comes to stolen hardware.

Comment: @Mike Scott How will you persuade cops or insurers they can't track lost/stolen/missing cars or many another thing by number? There's no law forcing the owner of a computer or any other valuable device to register it but fairly clearly the only "better" reasons for registering cars are public safety and tax revenue… nothing technical. The powers that be could, but "you" could not track anything.

Answer (score 3):

In short: **No, you can't**

**Why?**
Well, according to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204756), Find My Mac is the only Apple service that can help track or locate a lost Mac. If you didn’t set up Find My Mac before your Mac was lost, you can’t locate it, this includes the serial number.

**What Can You Try?**

- Your best bet would be to "report your lost or stolen Mac to local law enforcement. They might request the serial number of your computer." - Apple.
- There are databases for submitting lost device's serial numbers, these alert buyers for example when a device is marked stolen. I'd recommend getting onto this as soon as possible.

At set up and with macOS upgrades, Apple almost forces all this additional security because it works. By default, services like the Find My Mac are checked, you would have had to make the conscious decision not to enable the service. Naturally, what isn't enabled can't be called upon.

Answer (score 0):

ProGrammer's answer is correct from my previous experience with Apple. But you can request a note attached to your Apple account stating that a device with that serial number was stolen. When the device is brought to the Apple Store for repair and the Apple employee enters the serial number, it will show up as stolen.

Some Apple representatives will not tell you this and that you can do nothing unless you have "Find My Mac" enabled, which is true if you limit yourself to the iCloud system. You can request this extra step from the representative if you know about it.

To request a call with Apple, [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204315) has no direct contact, so instead go to [this page](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=psp&PRKEYS=PL107) and choose "The topic is not listed", then write an explanation at the next page, e.g.:

> My MacBook Pro computer was stolen and I want to give the serial numbers to Apple so it is black-listed.

You can and should also report the serial numbers on websites such as Immobilise.com . From talking to the Cambridgeshire police Constabulary:

> Immobilise.com is the main website we use, we don't use many others. It's also
> the most secure. It's also used by cash converters and second hand goods: before
> taking material, they check that website, and if they find a match, they call
> the police straight away.